# How to wrap incoming params with a specific attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if I have a **manually created html form** with the following input field

`<input type="text" name="email">`

it gives the following params `{"email" => "123" }`

How can I wrap it with `message_fields` without specifying it inside the form?

eg without the following

`<input type="text" name="message_fields[:email]">`

So I just want to wrap my params with `message_fields` from my controller.

controller strong params

```
params.permit(:comment, message_fields: {})
```

The idea is to assign all incoming params to `message_fields`

which is `t.hstore "message_fields"`

`"message_fields"=>{":email"=>"qew"}"`

Answer (score 0):

had to do the following but there definitely should be something better

```
  fields = @mailbox.allowed_fields.gsub(" ", "").split(",")
  h = {}
  fields.each do |f|
    h[f] = params[f]
  end
  attrs = message_params.tap do |p|
    p["message_fields"] = h
  end
```

then I just pass attr to create meth insted of message_params.